# Why does bottom-up parsing of right-recursive grammars require unbounded O(n) stack space?

Tags: compilers, parsers

I keep reading that while bottom-up parsing of a left-recursive grammar can be done in constant O(1) stack space, for a right-recursive grammar, we have to push the entire input stream onto the stack before popping any of them off. Why is this?

Let's say that I consider a simple right-recursive grammar
List -> elt List
| elt
, and I consider the string elt elt elt. When the parser pushes the first elt onto the stack, why doesn't it just immediately reduce it to List and then continue parsing?

Comment: When you say bottom-up  parsing, do you mean LR parsing? The answer to your question depends on the parsing algorithm you use. Also, the LR(k) parsing algorithm does not apply to all context free grammars.

Comment: Yep, I am indeed referring to LR parsers in this case. The book I’m using (Cooper, Torczon - Engineering a Compiler) refers to LR parsers as shift-reduce machines, which I’m familiar-ish with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: given the grammar
$$\begin{align}\textit{List}&\to \textbf{elt}\ \textit{List}\\
\textit{List}&\to \textbf{elt}
\end{align}$$
and the input
$$\textbf{elt elt elt}$$
Why doesn't the parser immediately reduce
$$\textit{List}\to \textbf{elt}$$
Suppose that it did. You would then have
$$\textit{List}\textbf{ elt elt}$$
Now what? No production starts with $\textit{List}$ so the parser is stuck.

The only way the parser can parse the entire input is to assume that the $\mathbf{elt}$ is the first symbol in $\textit{List}\to\textbf{elt}\textit{ List}$ and proceed from there, but that necessarily uses a stack slot to record the incomplete production.

To put it another way, if you use right-recursion, the unit production $\textit{List}\to\textbf{elt}$ applies to the *last* $\mathbf{elt}$ in the $\textit{List}$. In contrast, in a left-recursive grammar for the same language, the unit production would apply to the *first* $\mathbf{elt}$. Whether or not there is a semantic difference depends on your attribute actions; if there is no semantic difference, the left-recursive grammar will normally be prefered.

However, in many languages, there are also syntactic constraints which might suggest using a right-recursive grammar even though it uses up stack space. For example, the simplified grammar for a parameter list with optional unnamed trailing arguments (C99 varargs macros, for example):
$$\begin{align}\textit{Parameters}&\to \textbf{ID , }\ \textit{Parameters}\\
\textit{Parameters}&\to \textbf{ID}\\
\textit{Parameters}&\to \textbf{. . .}\\
\end{align}$$
Since the $\textbf{. . .}$ can only be at the end of the parameter-list, it's easiest to write the grammar as right-recursive.